# Can't log into Chat -- Failed Test 5: Storage

Tags: support, chat

Opening the Stack Exchange [chat help page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/help), I pass all of the tests up to, but not including, "Test 5: Storage".

I'm using the beta version of Chrome, 13.0.782.112 beta-m, and I can't figure out why it's not connecting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enable third-party cookies.  Options -> Settings -> Advanced (at the bottom) -> Content Settings -> Cookies, select "Allow local data to be set" and either uncheck "Block third-party cookies and site data" or add exceptions for the relevant sites (I think `[*.]sstatic.net`, `[*.]stackoverflow.com`, and `[*.]stackexchange.com`).

<s>Chrome currently has no way to allow all first-party cookies and block all third-party cookies except for exceptions.  This is **extremely** annoying.  I want to allow all first-party cookies and allow third-party only for stackauth.com, myself; I use no other sites that require them.</s>  This has been fixed.

Comment: have you suggested this as a feature for the Chrome team on their bugzilla? that is, third party cookie exception lists?

Comment: Google ignores all my bug reports, including serious privacy issues in Calendar, but here it is: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92481.  Everyone star it :P