# Chat requires that stackauth.com be online

Tags: support, chat

Until recently I have been able to use the chat feature just fine, but now I can't log in to chat. It seems that this feature is now relying on a cookie or web store at `stackauth.com`.

As I'm blocking third-party cookies and have no intentions of doing otherwise it seems that I can't use chat any more.

Why has this change happened? And could it be undone?

**Temporary fix:**
If you need to chat NOW, both balpha and the only part of the help page that I didn't read have a solution:

Go to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login (or the same URL on any Stack Exchange site where you're logged in) and click the button.

Comment: Your problem aside: [How does SO's new auto-login feature work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274) might be a nice read. And if you're using Safari, then note there's is no easy way [to delete the HTML5 Local Storage](http://superuser.com/questions/236558/how-to-clear-all-html5-local-storage-from-safari).

Comment: Note that [stackauth.com](http://stackauth.com) itself is not meant to be visited directly. So, just to be sure: [its very basic layout](http://i.stack.imgur.com/it4lx.png) does not indicate a problem.

Comment: @Arjan, Ivo Wetzel claimed he saw some 404's, that is what my edit reflects.

Comment: (I know, just wanted to make sure the layout doesn't qualify as "broken". But: there's an annoying CamelCase `FireFox` on that page. *That* qualifies as broken! `;-)`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure why you think this is new; it has *always* been this way.

For https://chat.stackoverflow.com and http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com, it's enough to be logged in to the parent site (because of the shared domain, chat has access to the parent cookie); for https://chat.stackexchange.com, login relies on the global authentication.

As the [help page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/help) says, we have a workaround for people with broken browsers: Go to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login (or the same URL on any Stack Exchange site where you're logged in) and click the button.

Comment: No luck with chat.stackowerflow.com either, but the fix-link worked, thanks! Now I'm just going to be a bitch and ask why, when there is a working solution, it isn't automated? As for the new thing, maybe I had an old cookie which expired?

Answer (score 7):

http://stackauth.com/ is used for network wide authentication on the Stack Exchange network. So if you don't whitelist that you won't be able to log in.

Comment: Well, I just need to beat the Chrome developers repeatedly in the head with something heavy until they decide to give me a working whitelist feature. I might as well try to move a mountain.

Comment: @eBusiness You can follow the feature request in my comments on the answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101803/cant-log-into-chat-failed-test-5-storage

Comment: @Matthew Read, star for that. I wonder if Mozilla got their act together since last time I checked?

Comment: There must be a bug. Firefox fails to log in to the chat starting this morning. Chrome (which I have no third party cookies blocked) can't login either. UPDATE: Allowed third party cookies in FX, still not able to log in.

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel, you are sure of this? No pages on the stack network show a little cookie with a red cross figure in the upper right corner in Chrome? If you are positive I'll reclassify this as a bug.

Comment: @eBusiness Getting 404's see my answer

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel, you can't just pull out silently, what happened and what happen'd?