# Unable to login because “Third Party Cookies Appear To Be Disabled”

Tags: support, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Third Party Cookies Appear To Be Disabled” When trying to login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103007/third-party-cookies-appear-to-be-disabled-when-trying-to-login)

I have a problem very similar to questions:

["Third Party Cookies Appear To Be Disabled" When trying to login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103007/third-party-cookies-appear-to-be-disabled-when-trying-to-login)

[Why does registration require third-party cookies to be enabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126764/why-does-registration-require-third-party-cookies-to-be-enabled)

[Getting "Third Party Cookies Appear To Be Disabled" in Google Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138975/getting-third-party-cookies-appear-to-be-disabled-in-google-chrome)

None of these questions have solved my problem and I have tried every suggestion. I do have a different set up so I thought I would create a new question.

I set up a new installation of Windows 8 Enterprise (RTM, not beta) and before installing any programs or changing any default settings I immediately tried to log into SO and I was unable to log in because of the thirdy party cookie issue describe in the other questions.  This is using IE10 with default settings.  I then installed Chrome and hit the same problem. The new installation was not added to a domain.  I am writing this question on a different computer (laptop) that runs Windows 8 Enterprise that has been added to a domain. If I log off the laptop and log in using a local user account (not a domain user), I run into the exact same cookie problem.  I just logged into another laptop computer (Win7 Pro and not on a domain) and I again run into the cookie problem.  I do not have any problem logging into any other site (Facebook, Google, MSDN, etc.) under any of these computer/user scenerios.

I'm stumped on how to log into SO on the Windows 8 new install.  Also, the link message below the third party cookie message "You can continue and log in manually however." does not work.  When I try to log in using that link, I get the "Not Found - This page could not be found." message described in each of the SO links referenced above. This leaves me locked out of SO using the computer/user scenarios described above.