# New user experience in IE ends at "third-party cookies"

Tags: discussion, new-users, cookies, sign-up

When you are new user trying to ask your first question, you'll get stuck after 5 steps:

1. Go to http://stackoverflow.com
2. Click `ask a question`
3. Click `click here to sign up`
4. Wait +/- 15 seconds
5. Enter a username and password
6. Error appears: `Third Party Cookies Appear To Be Disabled`

"Reset all zones to default level" leaves IE in a state where it blocks third-party cookies. If Internet Explorer disables third-party cookies by default, why does Stack Exchange use them?

And it [looks like](http://arstechnica.com/business/2013/02/firefox-22-will-block-third-party-cookies/) Firefox will soon block them too, and Safari already does.

If Stack Exchange requires the cookies, should it include instructions on how to "add an exception"?

Comment: What makes you assume that cookies are disabled by default in IE?  Are you sure you haven't simply disabled them even though that's not the default behavior?

Comment: @Servy: "Reset all zones to default level" leaves IE in a state where it blocks third-party cookies.  Looks like [FireFox will soon block them too](http://arstechnica.com/business/2013/02/firefox-22-will-block-third-party-cookies/).

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi What broader concern of cookie use?

Comment: So are we making the claim in this question that advertisers who place ads on Stack Exchange are using *third-party cookies*, and that Stack Exchange won't let you use the site unless third-party cookies are enabled?

Comment: @Robert Ah, whoops. My confusion.

Comment: But I thought that you could now signup on SE using a simple ID/Password combination.  Why would StackAuth (if that's owned by SE) be considered a third party?  Because it's on a different domain?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: the question is about what a new user who is trying to ask a question for the first time experiences. Not sure where you got the advertiser reference.

Comment: That's what a "third party" is.  An advertiser.  Do you see where I'm going with this?  Turning on third-party cookies just to satisfy StackAuth is a major inconvenience, if your MO is to always have such cookies turned off to block advertiser data mining.

Comment: The error message doesn't come along with [a link that lets you continue anyway](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126764/why-does-registration-require-third-party-cookies-to-be-enabled/127003#127003)?

Comment: Related: [Stack Exchange and third party cookies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109126)

Comment: @TimStone: That link is no longer there.  It just says "This site depends on third-party cookies, please add an exception for https://openid.stackexchange.com/."

Comment: @Andomar Let me know if the answers in the other question don't help you. It is pretty old, but it can't hurt to try.

Comment: @AnnaLear: I know how to enable third party cookies ;)  The question is if this is an acceptable experience for first time users.

Comment: I have third party cookies disabled in opera but I don't have any problems with SE. So I wouldn't be surprised if that error message is a red herring.